# P(F > x) : what do you call this?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, terminology, definition

What do you call P(F > x) (e.g. P(F > 4.2)? I'm trying to figure out a formula to arrive at the number given after the > sign using just two given degrees of freedom and I figured that if I knew the name of it I would be able to google it up. Thank you.

Comment: Some more context might help. Where did you encounter this notation?

Comment: I was given just two degrees of freedom (v1 and v2) and am supposed find P(F > 4,2) and have no idea how to do that. It appears the answer options are alpha numbers (0.01, 0.025, 0,05 and 0.1) so the formula should arrive at one of those numbers. That's the only context I have.

Comment: If that's all you have to go on, then I suspect that the question itself is faulty (unless there's some convention I'm unaware of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's often call the *survival function*, usually denoted $S(t)$. Note $S(t)=1-F(t)$.

It gives the probability of survival beyond time $t$, if the random variable represents the time of death/failure.

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome. I can’t believe this question was voted closed, I knew immediately what you were talking about. I guess the close-voters haven’t heard of survival functions. :/